# Adding zipper to animated character with clothes

Tags: animation, workflow, cloth-simulation

I'm quiet frustrated. I animated a character and now i'm about to make the clothes or better to add some details. I basically copied the mesh of the animated character, duplicated it, seperated it and let it use the same weights. Thats all working absolutely fantastic. But now i just want to add a zipper to the top clothing and follow the animation properly...like it should stay in the same position of the top. I treid anything thaat came to my mind, using constraints (child of),parenting the zipper to a curve with a shrinkwarp modifier (targeted to the top) with follow curve i even tried to manually weight paint all of the zipper but there war always some small problems like a part of the zipper is under the top clothing.
Someone there with an idea how to fix that?

Greatings

[image: this is how the zipper should look like the whole animation, its more or less just a detail and non functional]
[image: This is what it looks like with every thing i tried, not all of it is visible.]

PS: I didn't use cloth sim, because its really skinny clothes and parenting it to the bones works absolutely fine as said.

Comment: You really just need to tweak the weights of the zipper but that can be tedious. have you tried to shrinkwrap a curve onto the clothes and link the zipper to it?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your tip. But i use a shrinkwarp on a curve, it works actually pretty well on the bottom part, but the upper part is the problem....the shrinkwarp offset could solve the problem for this part but makes it look bad in the part beneath. I thought about splitting the zipper in top and bottom section with individual curves, but thats to much effort for 8secs of visabilaty. Because the zipper is looking okay for most of the animation, i ended up keyframing the bad parts by hooking the shrinkewarped curve to empty with armature constraints. Wasn't too much effort for that :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself....i'm sharing it, just in case someone else is having aa similar problem.
I made for things to make it work:

1. Array the zipper chain along a curve
2. Shrinkwarp the curve to the clothing part
3. Add an armature constraint to the curve
   -Use as many targetbones as in range or might have impact (compare the weights
   and bones used for the clothing part)
   -adjust the weights to get as close to the targeted result as possible

The last step is not ideal but it works, i just didn't want to use more time for such a little detail:

4. Hook the parts of the curve wich aren't perfect, add an armature constraint with the nearest bone as target and then keyframe it like every 10 frames..

Thats my solution it works very well but does include some more effort than i wished :p

Answer (score 0):

another update, i found the mistake while keframing it. My fault was to use a converted object as curve. that caused many problems, because the transitions weren't alwas that smooth. Keyframing works, but its too much work compared to the possibility to just use a native bezier curve with shrinkwarp parented to the bones. Or even better, go into edit mode select everything with a, right click and select "set spline type> bezier" as well as "set handle type> aligned".